# The requestor IP address is not whitelisted - Azure Twilio Send Grid

Tags: azure, powershell, twilio, sendgrid

I have used Twilio SendGrid service in azure for sending emails. I have used the following PowerShell script:

```
#region variables

param(
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $sendGridApiKey,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $toEmailAddress,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $ccEmailAddress
)

#endregion


#region MainScript

#******************************************************************************
# Script body
# Execution begins here
#******************************************************************************
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

        $sub = "Test Environment Details"

        $bodyHtml = "<html>
                        <head>
                            <style>
                                table {
                                    border-collapse: collapse;
                                    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                                }

                                td, th {
                                    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                                    text-align: left;
                                    padding: 8px;
                                }
                            </style>
                        </head>
                        <body style='color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>
                            Dear Developers Team,
                            <p>Your request for creating the resources was completed.</p>
                            <p>Test Environment Details:</p>
                            <p style='white-space:pre;word-wrap: break-word;overflow: hidden;'></p>
                            <p>Thank you </br> Your DevopsTeam</p>
                        </body>
                    </html>"

        # Create a body for sendgrid
        $Body = @{
            "personalizations" = @(
                @{
                    "to"      = @(
                        @{
                            "email" = $toEmailAddress
                        }
                    )
                    "cc"      = @(
                        @{
                            "email" = $ccEmailAddress
                        }
                    )
                    "subject" = $sub
                }
            )
            "content"          = @(
                @{
                    "type"  = "text/html"
                    "value" = $bodyHtml
                }
            )
            "from"             = @{
                "email" = "support@xyz.com"
            }
        }

        $BodyJson = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

        #Header for SendGrid API
        $Header = @{
            "authorization" = "Bearer $sendGridApiKey"
        }

        #Send the email through SendGrid API
        $Parameters = @{

            Method      = "POST"

            Uri         = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"

            Headers     = $Header

            ContentType = "application/json"

            Body        = $BodyJson

        }

        Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters

#endregion
```

But whenever I execute the above PS script from Azure DevOps release pipeline using Azure PowerShell task then I’m getting the following error:

> The requestor IP address is not whitelisted

Note:

I have created the API key with full access in SendGrid and then used the same key in the above PS script.

Comment: It looks like you have [IP Access Management](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/ip-access-management) enabled and you have not approved the IP address that Azure DevOps is using to make requests from.

Comment: @philnash, I have checked the `IP Access Management` of my Send Grid. In that I didn't see any IP address under the `Recent Access Attempts`  section.

Comment: Sounds like this is a job for [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) then.